# Variable not updating via php function

Tags: php, variables, scope

I've followed the wc3 tutorial on echoing php variables to denote incorrect input fields pretty much to the letter. I don't understand why this isn't working.

I have some weird scoping issue:

tools.php:

```
if(!isset($_POST)){
    $name_error = "";
}
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    $_SESSION['current'] = $_POST;
    validateForm();
}
```

index.php:

```
<span class="error"><?php echo $name_error; ?></span>
```

tools.php:

```
function validateForm() {
    $cust = $_SESSION['current']['cust'];
    $usermovie = $_SESSION['current']['movie'];
    $userseats = $_SESSION['current']['seats'];
    if(!preg_match('/[a-zA-Z ]+/', $cust['name']) || empty($cust['name'])){
        $name_error = "a-z only.";
        echo $name_error;
    } else{
        $_SESSION['bookings'][] = $_SESSION['current'];
        echo 'pass';
        $name_error = "";
    }

}
```

I know it's hitting the function and updating the value of $name_error because it echos the correct value from the function. Likewise, if I manually set the value of $name_error to a string it appears correctly in the error span. The value of $name_error in the span does NOT update when I just submit form/run the function normally though.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any value. Return the `$name_error` value like this:

```
if(!isset($_POST)){
    $name_error = "";
}
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    $_SESSION['current'] = $_POST;
    $name_error = validateForm();
}

function validateForm() {
    $cust = $_SESSION['current']['cust'];
    $usermovie = $_SESSION['current']['movie'];
    $userseats = $_SESSION['current']['seats'];
    if(!preg_match('/[a-zA-Z ]+/', $cust['name']) || empty($cust['name'])){
        $name_error = "a-z only.";
    } else{
        $_SESSION['bookings'][] = $_SESSION['current'];
        echo 'pass';
        $name_error = "";
    }
    return $name_error;
}
```

Comment: Actually man this isn't the issue. I'm not calling the function in the span I'm echoing the variable and the variable is declared outside of the function scope so it should update. Either way, returning the value doesn't work.

Comment: Did you apply my approach?

Comment: I did, I worked it out I had to declare $name_error as global at the start of the function - like I said I'm not calling the function inside the span I'm just echoing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, needed to declare

```
global $name_error;
```

at the start of the function - can anyone give me a way to return the result of individual functions inside the error spans though? I obviously can't just call them there.